# Obtener una lista de Maps reducida de otra lista de Maps en dart o flutter

Tags: lista, flutter, dart, map

Tengo esta lista:

```
data = [
{"serie" : "F001", "numero" : "1", "estado" : "1"},
{"serie" : "F001", "numero" : "2", "estado" : "1"},
{"serie" : "F001", "numero" : "3", "estado" : "1"},
{"serie" : "F001", "numero" : "4", "estado" : "1"}
]
```

Deseo obtener esta nueva lista sin los estados:

```
dataNew = [
{"serie" : "F001", "numero" : "1"},
{"serie" : "F001", "numero" : "2"},
{"serie" : "F001", "numero" : "3"},
{"serie" : "F001", "numero" : "4"}
]
```

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solamente recorre el listado de Maps y elimina el key `estado`.

```dart
  final data = [
    {"serie": "F001", "numero": "1", "estado": "1"},
    {"serie": "F001", "numero": "2", "estado": "1"},
    {"serie": "F001", "numero": "3", "estado": "1"},
    {"serie": "F001", "numero": "4", "estado": "1"}
  ];
  data.forEach((map) => map.remove('estado'));
  print(data);
```

Comment: Gracias amigo estaba cerquita de llegar a ese codigo, pero me hice bolas jajaja. Gracias

Comment: Hola @diegoveloper un favor si necesitara convertir el nuevo data a un String como lo haria.

Comment: puedes crear la pregunta aquí en stackoverflow y la respondo, pon más detalles